# Open Internet Explorer with embedded PDF

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, vbscript

I am launching IE with a variable, that opens an PDF document that is embedded within IE.  Unfortunately, I keep getting a prompt to open/save/cancel.  I just want the PDF to load in IE.
I created a batch file that works, but I need to use VBS to hide the address bar (do not want to work with kiosk mode for IE through batch file.

I run the VB Script as follows:

```
>test.vbs 123
```

My code is then:

```
Set oIE1 = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")

acc=Wscript.Arguments(0)

oIE1.Navigate "http://somplace/" & acc
oIE1.Visible = 1
oIE1.AddressBar = 0
oIE1.StatusBar = 0
oIE1.ToolBar = 0
oIE1.MenuBar = 0
```

But when IE opens, I get the save/open/cancel prompt which I must answer, and then the PDF opens in adobe reader.  Where I just want it to open within IE.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link from Adobe's website. It explains some Adobe Reader settings that you may need to change in order for PDF's to load properly within Internet Explorer and other browsers.

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html

Also, in Adobe Reader's preferences (`Edit->Preferences`), click the `Internet` page. There are options here that control how PDF's are viewed in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but that did not resolve this.
When I use a batch file the intended action works correctly and opens the PDF within IE.  But when I use VB Script I get the open/save/cancel prompt using the code in my original question.  I want to avoid this at the vb script level, so that I do not have to have other browsers modified to support this script.
Cheers!

Comment: How are you launching the PDF in your batch file?

Answer (score 0):

give it a try with this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,acc
URL = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Téléchargements\Vbscript.pdf"
Call IE_Run_PDF(URL) 'locally
'***************************************************
Sub IE_Run_PDF(URL)
    Dim objShell,MaCmd,Titre,fso
    Titre = "Run a PDF File with Internet Explorer"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(URL) Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    msgbox("iexplore.exe " & DblQuote(URL)),VbInformation,Titre
    MaCmd = "iexplore.exe "& DblQuote(URL) &""
    objShell.Run(MaCmd)
    Else
        MsgBox "The File " & DblQuote(URL) &" Dosen't Exists !",VbCritical,Titre
    End If
End Sub
'***************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***************************************************
URL = "http://repository.root-me.org/Programmation/VB/"
acc = "FR%20-%20Le%20language%20VBScript.pdf"
Call IE_Run_Net(URL,acc) 'Run on internet
'***************************************************
Sub IE_Run_Net(URL,acc)
Dim oIE1
Set oIE1 = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE1.Navigate(URL & acc)
oIE1.Visible = 1
oIE1.AddressBar = 0
oIE1.StatusBar = 0
oIE1.ToolBar = 0
oIE1.MenuBar = 0
End Sub
```